# How to recreate this wireframe looking effect

Tags: modeling, rendering

I would like to recreate something like this using blender, if someone knows please explain it to me.

thanks in advice.

[image]

Comment: The effect you are looking for is called "Plexus" as far as I know.
Please see here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28789/create-plexus-plugin-like-effect

Also, try searching youtube for "blender animation nodes plexus"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. maybe you want to animate this, in which case this answer would need expanding..

But as a still, this is a close shot:

[image]

It involves:

- A distorted plane with a Triangulation and a Wireframe modifier with a matte black material
- A particle system to place a 'vertex' at every vertex, with the same material
- A duplicate of the plane with a glass material, very low IOR, (no Wireframe, flat shaded)
- A long lens on the camera, to keep vertices about the same size in shot
- A shallow depth of field set for the camera
- A Background shader for the world, large-scale noise to reflections in the glass, but white to the camera and transmission through the glass.

[image]

I probably should have used Dupliverts, not particles.. but can't replace the Blend right now...

Comment: Also, there is animation nodes ♥
https://youtu.be/dS2eid2hs-A?t=202

Comment: @L0Lock    There you go.. I never even heard of Plexus... I know _nothing_ ! :D

Comment: see the comments under the question ;)