# Texture Question

Tags: rendering

Good day

I'm new to blender and the forum, I hope someone will be able to help me.
I want to make something like the picture attached, but only the ball part, not the face and the brain, only the ball wires, where the white wires must be visible, one color and the points between the wires another color, and the black background transparent.
Is there somewhere that I can find a texture like this, or how would I create my own texture?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Bubble]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28789/create-plexus-plugin-like-effect?noredirect=1&lq=1